# Display category name in Woocommerce Single product view

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Hello my requirement is I want to achieve the functionality as shown here

https://www.perniaspopupshop.com/mani-bhatia-white-embroidered-lehenga-set-mbtc022107.html

A product is listed in different categories but I want to Show only the Designer's Name (Clickable) which is also a category so that when that designer is clicked then all the products under this designer are shown.

This is my title.php file to show the title

```
   <code>
    <?PHP
       if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
      }
     ?>
     <h1 class="product-title product_title entry-title">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      </code>
```

you can refer to this page where I want the changes
https://www.zowed.com/shop/product/yellow-gown/

Now instead of showing the product name I want the Category to be shown
[image]

Please help I have used

```
<code>
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product-title entry-title">'.$term->name.'</h1>';
    }
    ?>
</code>
```

This shows the names of the category but not the Designer name under the Designer category
So I did this

```
<code>
<?php
function wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
    // Get post by post ID.
    if ( ! $post = get_post() ) {
        return '';
    }
 
    // Get post type by post.
    $post_type = $post->post_type;
 
    // Get post type taxonomies.
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );
 
    $out = array();
 
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){
 
        // Get the terms related to post.
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );
 
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            if ($taxonomy->label == 'Product categories')
            {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out[] = sprintf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
                    esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
                    esc_html( $term->name )
                );
            }
            $out[] = "\n</ul>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $out );
}

echo wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links(); ?>
</code>
```

Now it shows all the Product Category

Please help

Comment: It will show all categories because it is related to all of them.

Comment: How can i show only the Designer name; who is attached to that product